# Mongoose $unwind returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have saw similar but nothing solved by problem. Thats why I am posting the question again. This is my mongoose schema

```
'use strict';

//Importing packages
const Mongoose    = require('mongoose');

//Declaring schema 
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema({
    moduleName  : {type: String, unique: true},
    parentModule: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'module'},
    status      : {type: Number, default: 0},
    sortOrder   : {type: Number, default: 1},
    createdBy   : {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'admin'},
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

//Exporting packages
module.exports = Mongoose.model('module', Schema);
```

In my collection, parentModule column again referring same collection.

When i am doing aggregate function with $unwind output data was empty. My collection have one-to-one relationship. So that retrieving parent module have to be object rather than array. That's the reason i used $unwind. But its shows empty. When i remove $unwind it shows the data.

Here my code:

```
const query = ModuleModel
.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {parentModule: {$ne: null}}
    },
    {
        $project: {
            parentModule: {$cond: [{$eq: }]}
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "modules",
            "localField": "parentModule",               
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":  "parents"
        }
    },      
    {
        "$unwind": {
            path: "$parent",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
], function(error, data){
    console.log(data);
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
        return response(error);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("test");
        return response({data: data});
    }
});
```

When i remove $unwind my output look like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "58b509642fb32d1a1436efdd",
      "updatedAt": "2017-02-28T05:23:48.531Z",
      "createdAt": "2017-02-28T05:23:48.531Z",
      "moduleName": "roles1",
      "parentModule": "58b3d64244307f3e2fddd1e1",
      "sortOrder": 1,
      "status": 0,
      "__v": 0,
      "parents": [
        {
          "_id": "58b3d64244307f3e2fddd1e1",
          "updatedAt": "2017-02-27T07:33:22.396Z",
          "createdAt": "2017-02-27T07:33:22.396Z",
          "moduleName": "roles",
          "parentModule": null,
          "sortOrder": 1,
          "status": 0,
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here my parents column shows as an array, I have seen this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-joins-in-mongodb-nosql-databases). They change the array of objects into object using $unwind. But i didn't get the output same way. Some the parentModule can be null on the collection.

If anyone know about this help me.

Comment: Is it just a typo in the query? The array is called _parents_ (with an _s_), but your query is trying to unwind _parent_ (without the _s_) ?

Comment: @VinceBowdren thanks vince i didn't notice that